# How can I prevent Visual Studio from replacing my exception pane with the Build Output pane?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, error-list

When I Ctrl+Shift+B my app, it gives me an Error List. But when I 2-click one of the errors, it then replaces the Error List with the Build Output. Closing the Build Output doesn't return me to the Error List, so I have to Ctrl+Shift+B again to get it back.

Is there a way to circumvent this by not showinng the Output pane when an Error List exists? Or making the Error List "sticky" or changing its Z Order to always be on top?

Comment: Is your ErrorList docked into a panel that has "Auto-Hide" set?

Comment: They both display in the same spot on the lower left 2/3rds of the screen - with the Solution Explorer and Properties panes inhabiting the right third. "AutoHide" (which I wasn't aware of) is grayed out among the contextual options of the ErrorList.

Comment: If it is grayed-out, it means it is already selected. Select Dock, then it will not hide after you click on something.

Comment: Some cat wearing a black hood must have come in here and set it to "Autohide"